# "/usr/libexec/replayd" high CPU usage all the time (around ~90%)

Tags: macos

I don't remember installing anything new, but there's a process called replayd that is constantly consuming over 90% of the CPU. If I kill it, it comes back immediately.

What could it be?

UPDATE: It looks like the culprit is Slack, after closing it, the process ended.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`replayd` is a MacOS daemon to support screen recording and video capture.

Don't forget that the %CPU reported in Activity Monitor for each process is *per core*. So if you have an 8-core CPU, 90% is 11.25% of your total CPU.

Comment: I had this happen after twice trying to share a window on macOS 14.3 with Chrome (latest).  I was using Google Meet and twice the share screen/window failed.  I finally just shared the entire screen and it worked.  The amount of CPU time accumulated was about 21 hours, at the time I noticed it, and 21 hours puts it at the time I used Google Meet.

Comment: This was triggered by DisplayLink Manager for me. Quitting and restarting DisplayLink Manager fixed it.